# JHipster: One-to-one relation with User

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

Since v2.5 JHipster allows to make many-to-one relations with the User entity created by the generator.

I understand making bidirectional or one-to-many would be a completely different issue but, is there a way to make a one-to-one relation with the user or should I make a many-to-one and then change the @annotation for converting it in a one-to-one? Would this work?

Otherwise I guess it would be possible to just not create a new relation in case there's already one.

What would be your approach?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, it works in my case. Put this relationship in *Superman.json*.
**Dropdown select in the adding menu works fine.**

```
    {
        "relationshipId": 1,
        "relationshipName": "user",
        "otherEntityName": "user",
        "relationshipType": "one-to-one",
        "otherEntityField": "login",
        "otherEntityRelationshipName": "superman",
        "ownerSide": true
    }
```

Jhipster v2.27.2